# Pandas DataFrame- merging two DataFrames to determine history/transitions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to track the movement history of a set of deliveries.  I have two dataframes- the first is the last known location of each delivered item, before the history began:

```
prior_location = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Date': '2019-07-15', 'Location': '123 Main St.'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Date': '2019-07-17', 'Location': '15 First Ave.'}
])
```

The next is the delivery history:

```
deliveries = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Date': '2019-08-01', 'DeliveredTo': '191 Long Rd.'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Date': '2019-08-03', 'DeliveredTo': '582 Pleasant Court'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Date': '2019-08-04', 'DeliveredTo': 'SHOP'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Date': '2019-07-30', 'DeliveredTo': 'YARD'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Date': '2019-08-01', 'DeliveredTo': '191 Long Rd.'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Date': '2019-08-05', 'DeliveredTo': '15 Lake Drive'}
])
```

My goal is to generate a dataframe with a `PickedUpFrom`, and `DeliveredTo` column for each delivery. E.g.- the final dataframe should look something like:

```
history = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Date': '2019-08-01', 'PickedUpFrom': '123 Main St.', 'DeliveredTo': '191 Long Rd.'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Date': '2019-08-03', 'PickedUpFrom': '191 Long Rd.', 'DeliveredTo': '582 Pleasant Court'},
    {'Equip': 'A-1', 'Date': '2019-08-04', 'PickedUpFrom': '582 Pleasant Court', 'DeliveredTo': 'SHOP'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Date': '2019-07-30', 'PickedUpFrom': '123 Main St.', 'DeliveredTo': 'YARD'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Date': '2019-08-03', 'PickedUpFrom': 'YARD', 'DeliveredTo': '191 Long Rd.'},
    {'Equip': 'A-2', 'Date': '2019-08-04', 'PickedUpFrom': '15 First Ave.', 'DeliveredTo': '15 Lake Drive'},
])
```

Notice that the first entry `PickedUpFrom` for each piece of equipment comes from the `prior_location` table, and the subsequent ones are the prior row (for that piece of equipment) `DeliveredTo`.

Any thoughts on an efficient way to do this (my actual data set has several thousand pieces of equipment).

A couple of things to note- there is only one delivery per piece of equipment, per date (so `A-1` will only be at one location on a given day).  Also, the `prior_location` dataframe is guaranteed to have the last location, prior to the first element in the deliveries dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way first `groupby` + `shift` , then `fillna` with `prior_location`

```
deliveries['PickedUpFrom']=deliveries.groupby('Equip').DeliveredTo.shift()
s=prior_location.set_index('Equip')['Location'].reindex(deliveries.Equip).values
deliveries['PickedUpFrom'].fillna(pd.Series(s,index=deliveries.index),inplace=True)
deliveries
Out[51]: 
  Equip        Date         DeliveredTo        PickedUpFrom
0   A-1  2019-08-01        191 Long Rd.        123 Main St.
1   A-1  2019-08-03  582 Pleasant Court        191 Long Rd.
2   A-1  2019-08-04                SHOP  582 Pleasant Court
3   A-2  2019-07-30                YARD       15 First Ave.
4   A-2  2019-08-01        191 Long Rd.                YARD
5   A-2  2019-08-05       15 Lake Drive        191 Long Rd.
```